# Deleting replies from a telegram bot

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot written in Python. It sends message on specific commands as per mentioned in code. I want to delete **the replies** sent by this bot suppose after **X** seconds. There is a telegram bot API that deletes the message

```
https://api.telegram.org/botBOTID/deleteMessage?chat_id=?&message_id=?
```

To delete the message we need **chat id** and **message id**. To get the **chat id** and **message id** of the replied message by the bot, I need to keep reading all the messages (even from users) and find these id's. This will increase a lot of overhead on the bot.

Is there any other way to find these **id's**  without reading all the messages?

Comment: Can't you just get the last messages or?

Comment: @AfloroaieRobert If the group is having many members, it will have many messages incoming..

Comment: Hey Did You Find Any Solution To Delete Bot Messages In Supergroup?

Answer (score 1):

This is the `Chat` object. It contains the identifier of the chat.

[image: partial screenshot of chat object]

This is the `Message` object. It contains the identifier for that message and a `Chat` object representing the coversation where it resides.

[image: partial screenshot of message object]

The `sendMessage` REST function returns the Message you sent on success.

[image: partial screenshot of sendMessage documentation]

So your solution here is to store the `Message` object you get when sending a message, and then call the delete api with the parameters from the stored objects (`Message.message_id` and `Message.chat.id`).

Regarding Python you can use the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module to store objects in files.

Answer (score 1):

In nodeJs I use these codes to delete the replies sent by bot after 10 seconds:

```
let TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
let bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

bot.on('message', (msg) => {
    let chatId = msg.chat.id;
    let botReply = "A response from the bot that will removed after 10 seconds"
    bot.sendMessage(chatId ,botReply)
        .then((result) => { setTimeout(() => {
            bot.deleteMessage(chatId, result.message_id)
        }, 10 * 1000)})
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```